# Google Speech API V2

Tags: google-speech-api

I have followed [this link](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys) to generate API keys, but the Speech API was not found on the console.

The application example I'm following is here: https://github.com/gillesdemey/google-speech-v2/

I keep on getting an error:

> Your client does not have permission to get URL.

What's the problem?

Comment: Did you read the bold yellow warning at the top of the Chromium page you linked to?

Answer (score 29):

You have to be a member of chromium-dev discussion list *before* you can enable the Speech API in your Google Developers Console.

1. Go to [Chromium Dev group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/chromium-dev) and click Join the list.
   **Do not post to the group regarding the Google Speech API, as it is completely off topic.**
2. Go back to [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com), select your project, enter APIs & Auth / APIs. You'll now see Speech API. Click to enable it.
3. Go to Credentials, Create new Key, Server Key. You may optionally specify a list of IPs, for security.

You now may make queries to Google Speech API v2. Keep in mind that this is an experimental API, and limited to 50 queries per day per project.

Here's an example (using Linux):

```
arecord -D plughw:2,0 -f cd -t wav -d 10 -r 16000 | \
flac - -f --best --sample-rate 16000 -o out.flac; \
wget -O - -o /dev/null --post-file out.flac --header="Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=16000" \
"http://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?lang=en-us&key=ADD_YOUR_KEY_HERE&output=json" | \
sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g'
```

Comment: The reason you have to join chromium-dev is that the API is only intended to be used for Chromium development. Joining that group in order to try to get access to the API for some other use is solving the wrong problem. If you aren't doing Chromium development, you shouldn't use the API.

Comment: Wanted a proper way to use the google speech apis, if not for chromium-dev since it is applicable for many business cases.  https://cloud.google.com/speech/ is available now.  Still only allowing 2 minutes - will check if possible to use on larger files.

Comment: Does google speech to text APIs are available for public use. Can you please provide the documentation link for the APIs, I am unable to find it so.
Thanks

Comment: @Sanket: a lot has happened since my original answer, so your best bet option is to use the new [Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/), part of Google Cloud. Unfortunately it's not yet publicly available; you need to apply and wait for the invite.

Comment: how to apply for beta version @GuiAmbros

Comment: @chetanpanchal: Cloud Speech API is now available publicly; no need to apply for any beta. See cloud.google.com/speech

Comment: thanks @GuiAmbros I am already using google speech to text cloud api version1(google.cloud.speech.v1), I want to use version2(google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1) do you know from where I will be able to get its access, I have tried git repository but it gives me stable version 1