# Google Speech API still supported?

Tags: google-api

I just tried to register a project for use with the Google Speech API, and I couldn't see the API in the the list when I filtered it for the words "speech" or "voice". Is the API still supported?

I just found the new Web Speech API [here](http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html) Did this take the place of the Speech API v2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Speech API V2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485531/google-speech-api-v2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be a member of chromium-dev discussion list before you can enable the Speech API in your Google Developers Console.

1. Go to [Chromium Dev group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/chromium-dev) and click Join the list.
2. Go back to [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), select your project, enter APIs & Auth / APIs. You'll now see Speech API. Click to enable it.
3. Go to Credentials, Create new Key, Server Key. You may optionally specify a list of IPs, for security.

You now may make queries to Google Speech API v2. Keep in mind that this is an experimental API, and limited to 50 queries per day per project.

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485531/google-speech-api-v2) older post..
Answered by @gui-ambros

May this help you a little...

Comment: The reason you have to join chromium-dev is that the API is only intended to be used for Chromium development. Joining that group in order to try to get access to the API for some other use is solving the wrong problem. If you aren't doing Chromium development, you shouldn't use the API.